# How can I play .smil videos?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-player

I want to see some videos that are composed of one .smil file and two .rm files.
(the .smil says to play the two videos at the same time)

If I try to play the .smil, Totem player starts but shows me just one of the two .rm, so it's not useful.

I used to play them with reaplayer, but I seen that is no more supported, so I was wondering if there was a better solution.

Comment: Does VLC  play them?

Comment: no, it would be too simple ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to choose one because I haven't got much experience with it but here is a list of capable players for .smil files: http://www.w3.org/AudioVideo/#SMIL

Apparently http://www.ambulantplayer.org/ can play all the formats of smil files so I would recommend you start with this one.

You can build the source code following the instructions [here](https://wiki.andrewmercer.net/index.php/Ubuntu_-_Ambulant).

Hf and gl ;)

Comment: It looks good, but the only way to install it seems to compile it.. I was searching something in repos ot at least in a PPA..

Comment: Edited the answer to include a stable ppa, haven't really tested it so if you have any problems with it let me know so I can spend a bit more time finding one that is stable.

Comment: I think that it isn't for natty, this ambulant package is just for maverick..

Comment: Fixed with a wiki that described how to build from source. Just make sure you have the latest source package, im doing it now as a test.

Comment: As an option you can always try any of the players on that list!