# How to play realmedia / SMIL / rtsp audio references with start/end points

Tags: software-recommendation, music

I'm trying to play the song referenced at [A Prairie Home Companion: May 6, 2006 - Moonlight on the Colorado River lyrics](http://prairiehome.publicradio.org/programs/2006/05/06/scripts/moonlight.shtml).  For some of my friends, the "listen" link there plays just the song whose lyrics are listed.  But when I click on it (via Chrome on a Maverick system with Totem as my player), I hear the entire 2-hour program.  The listen link redirects to a SMIL file which references "rtsp://mprrm.publicradio.org/5559/phc/2006/05/06_phc.rm?start=00:00:04:10.0&end=00:00:07:08.0", which specifies a start time of 04:10 and an end time of 07:08.  But it seems that totem is ignoring the start and end times.

Are there open source music players in the Ubuntu repos that properly handle this link?

I'm guessing based on the [How can I play .smil videos? - Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63818/how-can-i-play-smil-videos) that Ambulant might handle it, but I guess that isn't yet in the repos?  And RealPlayer presumably works, but as pointed out at ([RealPlayerInstallationMethods - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RealPlayerInstallationMethods)), it isn't open source.

**Update**:

For Totem, the relevant upstream bug seems to be [Bug 424708 – Add support for starttime](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=424708), which is present in launchpad as [Bug #605370 “.smi files are not played correctly”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/605370) as @student pointed out.

For some insights on the relevant playlist format and editing see also [Video playlists with start and end times - Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8823/video-playlists-with-start-and-end-times)

I'm still looking for some way to play these videos as intended.

Comment: See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/605370

Comment: http://developer.gnome.org/totem-pl-parser/stable/TotemPlParser.html#TOTEM-PL-PARSER-FIELD-STARTTIME:CAPS

Comment: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=631401

Comment: See also [Video playlists with start and end times - Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8823/video-playlists-with-start-and-end-times).  Thanks for that question and the links, @student!

Comment: For Totem, the relevant upstream bug seems to be [Bug 424708 – Add support for starttime](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=424708)

Comment: @fossfreedom, I think this is still a good and relevant question which should be re-opened.  The fact that one app has a well-defined feature-request bug doesn't mean that there isn't some other way to play these videos as intended.

Comment: @nealmcb - reopened.  Please add  your comments as edits in your question.  This will bump it up the activity list.  Remember to regularly review this question by adding in stuff you have tried.  You may wish to think about a small bounty to give this more prominence.  Thanks.

Comment: @nealmcb has this problem been solved yet?